# Entity Framework chave estrangeira

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Meu domínio:

```
public class SBE_ST_CorpoDocente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SBE_ST_Curso> Cursos { get; set; }
}

public class SBE_ST_Curso
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SBE_ST_CorpoDocente> Coordenacao { get; set; }
}
```

Camada de interação com o banco:

```
public void Salvar(SBE_ST_Curso entidade)
    {
        var idsCoordenacao = entidade.Coordenacao.Select(c => c.Id).ToList();
        var coordenacao = contexto.CorpoDocente.Where(cd => idsCoordenacao.Contains(cd.Id)).ToList();
        if (entidade.Id > 0)
        {
            var cursoAlterar = contexto.Curso.First(x => x.Id == entidade.Id);
            cursoAlterar.Titulo = entidade.Titulo;
            cursoAlterar.Coordenacao = coordenacao;
            contexto.Entry(cursoAlterar).State = EntityState.Modified;
            contexto.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            entidade.Coordenacao = coordenacao;
            contexto.Curso.Add(entidade);
            contexto.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Quando insiro um novo registro funciona perfeitamente. Quando vou atualizar um registro ele dá erro. Se limpo a tabela que guarda os relacionamentos, ai consigo editar normal a primeira vez, depois dá o mesmo erro.

Erro:

> Additional information: An error occurred while saving entities that
>   do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The
>   EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot
>   be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions
>   while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in
>   your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

Analisando o IntelliTrace:

> Exception:Caught: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
>   'PK_dbo.SBE_ST_CursoSBE_ST_CorpoDocente'. Cannot insert duplicate key
>   in object 'dbo.SBE_ST_CursoSBE_ST_CorpoDocente'. The duplicate key
>   value is (8, 1). The statement has been terminated."
>   (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException) A
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was caught: "Violation of PRIMARY
>   KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.SBE_ST_CursoSBE_ST_CorpoDocente'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.SBE_ST_CursoSBE_ST_CorpoDocente'. The
>   duplicate key value is (8, 1). The statement has been terminated."
>   Time: 11/08/2014 15:28:19 Thread:Worker Thread[3508]

Fiz uma GAMBIARRA para resolver esse problema. (GAMBIARRA MESMO)

```
public void LimparRelacionamentos(int id)
{
    SqlConnection MinhaConexao = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BancoDados"].ConnectionString);
    MinhaConexao.Open();
    string query = "DELETE FROM SBE_ST_CursoSBE_ST_CorpoDocente WHERE SBE_ST_Curso_Id = " + id;
    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query, MinhaConexao);
    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MinhaConexao.Close();
}



 public void Salvar(SBE_ST_Curso entidade)
        {
            var idsCoordenacao = entidade.Coordenacao.Select(c => c.Id).ToList();
            var coordenacao = contexto.CorpoDocente.Where(cd => idsCoordenacao.Contains(cd.Id)).ToList();
            if (entidade.Id > 0)
            {
                var cursoAlterar = contexto.Curso.First(x => x.Id == entidade.Id);
                cursoAlterar.Titulo = entidade.Titulo;
                LimparRelacionamentos(entidade.Id);
                cursoAlterar.Coordenacao = coordenacao;
                contexto.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                entidade.Coordenacao = coordenacao;
                contexto.Curso.Add(entidade);
                contexto.SaveChanges();
            }
}
```

Comment: A gambiarra só faz você excluir o registro pra depois inserir de novo, o que não resolve corretamente o problema. Você poderia por favor corrigir o meu fork no GitHub pra que eu possa simular o problema por completo?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, editei o github, veja se agora dá certo!

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, adicionei uma resposta. Teria como você dar uma olhada?

Answer (score 7):

Você não está fazendo o contexto observar corretamente suas alterações. O contexto sempre pensa que a entidade que vem da tela é nova porque não carregou o registro existente antes. O certo seria carregar um novo registro se ele não possui Id (Id > 0). Caso contrário, você precisa indicar ao contexto que a entidade foi alterada por você, e que as informações atuais do objeto devem ser tratadas como verdadeiras.

Outra coisa é que:

```
cursoAlterar.Coordenacao = entidade.Coordenacao.Select(
    coordenacao => contexto.CorpoDocente.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == coordenacao.Id)).ToList();
```

Esta declaração faz o contexto sempre preencher `Coordenacao` de novo. Por mais que aparentemente não haja mudanças, o Entity Framework tem uma lógica que observa as variáveis. Como houve alteração, e você preencheu `Coordenacao` a partir da tela, ele tenta inserir os registros como se fossem novos. O certo seria preencher os dados com a varíavel **vinda do contexto**, e não da tela.

O código também pode ser trocado para algo mais simples e retirado diretamente do contexto, como por exemplo:

```
cursoAlterar.Coordenacao = contexto.CorpoDocente.Where(
    x => entidade.Coordenacao.Select(e => e.Id).Contains(x.Id))).ToList();
```

O resultado final fica mais ou menos assim.

```
public void Salvar(SBE_ST_Curso entidade)
{
    if (entidade.Id > 0)
    {
        // Esta linha tem que pelo menos levantar exceção, evitando inserir 
        // alguma bobagem no banco, por isso troquei para SingleOrDefault.
        var cursoAlterar = contexto.Curso.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == entidade.Id);

        cursoAlterar.Titulo = entidade.Titulo;
        cursoAlterar.Coordenacao = contexto.CorpoDocente.Where(
            x => entidade.Coordenacao.Select(e => e.Id).ToList().Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
        contexto.Entry(cursoAlterar).State = EntityState.Modified;

        contexto.SaveChanges();
    }
    else
    {
        cursoAlterar.Coordenacao = contexto.CorpoDocente.Where(
            x => entidade.Coordenacao.Select(e => e.Id).ToList().Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
        contexto.Curso.Add(entidade);

        contexto.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Fiz várias e várias correções no seu código. Coloquei tudo [em um repositório GitHub](https://github.com/cigano/Web_SBE). Para o que interessa para a pergunta, faltou uma lógica robusta que faça exclusão e inclusão de Corpos Docentes, como a explicada abaixo:

```
            // Entradas Excluídas
            var coordenacoesOriginais = contexto.Curso.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == cursoAlterar.Id).Coordenacao;

            foreach (var coordenacaoPossivelmenteExcluida in coordenacoesOriginais)
            {
                if (cursoAlterar.Coordenacao.All(c => c.Id != coordenacaoPossivelmenteExcluida.Id))
                {
                    contexto.CorpoDocente.Remove(coordenacaoPossivelmenteExcluida);
                }
            }

            // Novas Entradas
            foreach (var novaCoordenacao in coordenacao)
            {
                if (cursoAlterar.Coordenacao.All(c => c.Id != novaCoordenacao.Id))
                {
                    cursoAlterar.Coordenacao.Add(novaCoordenacao);
                }
            }

            contexto.SaveChanges();
```

Porém, note que ao excluir um Corpo Docente desta forma, você estará também excluindo o registro original, visto que a modelagem do banco está errada. Deve ser criada uma entidade associativa a mais que ligue Cursos a Corpos Docentes, algo como `CursoAssocCorpoDocente`. Aí vai das suas escolhas.

Comment: Acho que digitou errado o .Enty só encontrei o .Entry, porém não funcionou, gerou o mesmo erro.

Comment: Digitei ;) Estou corrigindo.

Comment: Agora gerou o seguinte erro: Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Dominio.SBE_ST_CorpoDocente'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: Acho que é a geração da lista de Id's: `entidade.Coordenacao.Select(e => e.Id)`. Experimente gerar essa lista fora, antes de chamar `contexto.CorpoDocente.Where()`.

Comment: Ou, melhor ainda, coloque um `ToList()` entre `Select()` e `Contains()`. Farei isso na resposta.

Comment: Mesmo erro! ... Edit: A expressão está com um parenteses a mais!

Answer (score 1):

Por serem 2 relacionamentos de 1 para muitos, o melhor é associar à lista de elementos do context, utilizando os ids do objeto passado.

```
public void Salvar(SBE_ST_Curso curso)
{
    var idsCoordenacao = curso.Coordenacao.Select(c => c.Id).ToList();
    var coordenacao = contexto.CorpoDocente.Where(cd => idsCoordenacao.Contains(cd.Id)).ToList();

    if (curso.Id > 0)
    {
        var cursoAlterar = contexto.Curso.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == curso.Id);
        cursoAlterar.Titulo = curso.Titulo;
        cursoAlterar.Coordenacao = coordenacao;
    }
    else
    {
         curso.Coordenacao = coordenacao;
         contexto.Curso.Add(curso);
    }

    contexto.SaveChanges();
}
```

Só pra reforçar, caso você não saiba, mas não é recomendado trabalhar com objetos que venham direto do Request, como parâmetros de ações do controlador devido a questões de segurança. Para isso, utilize sempre um modelo específico para a transferência de dados. Esses modelos são chamados de ViewModel por alguns e são apenas classes sem vículo algum, que servem apenas para transferir os dados.

No seu caso, você poderia ter uma classe para estes dados na forma de:

```
public class CursoViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public List<int> Coordenacao { get; set; }

    public static CursoViewModel MapearDoCurso(SBE_ST_Curso curso)
    {
        return new CursoViewModel
        {
            Id = curso.Id,
            Nome = curso.Nome,
            Coordenacao = curso.Coordenacao.Select(c => c.Id).ToList()
        };
    }

    public void MapearParaCurso(SBE_ST_Curso curso)
    {
        curso.Id = this.Id;
        curso.Nome = this.Nome;
        curso.Coordenacao = context.CorpoDocente.Where(c => this.Coordenacao.Contains(c.Id));
    }
}
```

Com esta estrutura e métodos auxiliares de mapeamento, você pode trabalhar com segurança, enviando e recebendo dados com esta classe e reaver o seu modelo na ação do controlador:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var curso = contexto.Cursos.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

    if (curso != null)
    {
        var cursoParaEditar = CursoViewModel.MapearDoCurso(curso);

        return View(cursoParaEditar);
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag["erro"] = "Curso inválido!";
        return View();
    }
}
```

Na volta, basta fazer o contrário, utilizando o método na instância `MapearParaCurso()`, passando uma referência para o curso com o ID que veio do método:

```
public ActionResult Edit(CursoViewModel cursoAlterado)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var curso = contexto.Cursos.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == cursoAlterado.Id);

        if (curso != null)
        {
            cursoAlterado.MapearParaCurso(curso);
            // caso não salve, utilize: contexto.Entry(curso).EntityState = EntityState.Modifyed;
            contexto.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag["erro"] = "Curso inválido!";
            return View();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag["erro"] = "Erros de validação!";
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou... Não ficou muito claro o conceito de ViewModel, porém acho que não cabe a esta pergunta esclarecimentos. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Voltou a dar problema, do nada... Existe alguma explicação? Uma solução?

Comment: @DiegoZanardo O `ViewModel` basicamente é um `Model` que não é persistido. Ele só serve pra popular a tela e recolher dados dela. Como o `Controller` pode recebê-lo, o que a resposta propõe é organizar melhor o que vem da sua `View`.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, quanto ao erro, porque voltou a acontecer? Na primeira vez que alterei foi normal, agora hoje voltou o erro.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Qual o erro?

Comment: O mesmo que o da pergunta!

Comment: @DiegoZanardo, o erro voltou? O que foi feito antes que o fez funcionar e o que foi feito depois? Você usa controle de versão?

Comment: @rcdmk, não tem controle de versão. E não alterei nada, relacionado a isso.

Comment: Hum... Primeira coisa: SEMPRE utilize controle de versão. Nem que seja uma cópia do código que está funcionando para outra pasta. Mas git não é nada difícil de utilizar, ainda mais com o TortoiseGit. Dê uma olhada.

Comment: Segundo: Se ele chegou a funcionar, foi depois de fazer a alteração que sugeri?

Comment: Então @rcdmk, fiz as alterações que sugeriu e funcionou. Então passei a popular o banco, e então depois de uns dias voltou o erro.

Comment: Provavelmente há algum problema com a estrutura do banco de dados. Está muito estranho isso. É provável que o erro nunca tenha sido resolvido. Só parou de dar o erro porque você deve ter esvaziado o banco. Experimente com o banco vazio e tente ver se roda. (Ps.: faça um favor a você mesmo, instale o [Git](http://msysgit.github.io/) com o [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) ou o [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/). Ambos tem em pt-BR.)

Comment: @rcdmk, para gerar o banco utilizo o Migrations, e já tentei utilizar outro banco.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Não está claro pra mim ainda o porquê do seu erro. Você poderia criar uma conta no GitHub, colocar seu projeto lá e compartilhar o link na pergunta? Com o fonte, podemos testar e identificar melhor o problema.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, acredito que seja isso: https://github.com/dgo13/Web_SBE. Acredito que retirei todos os dados de banco e ftp. Mas como é meu primeiro uso do github, gostaria que se houvesse me notificasse.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Fiz um pull request pra você no GitHub com algumas alterações. Só aceitar, baixar as alterações de volta e arrumar o que falta pra conseguir salvar registros, porque eu não conseguir salvar nada.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, deletei sem querer meu repositório no github, não sei mexer. Acredito que o erro se dava ao upload das fotos.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Você pode até ter excluído, mas ainda tenho meu fork. Só baixar de volta: https://github.com/cigano/Web_SBE

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode ter uma relacionamento ManyToMany desse jeito. Utilize `EntityTypeConfiguration` da lib `System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration`. E crie o Mapeamento:

```
public class SBE_ST_CorpoDocenteMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<SBE_ST_CorpoDocente>
{
    public SBE_ST_CorpoDocenteMap()
    {
        HasMany(t => t.Cursos)
            .WithMany(t => t.Coordenacao)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("TB_CURSO_COORDENADO", "schema");
                m.MapLeftKey("id_curso");
                m.MapRightKey("id_coordenado");
            });
    }
}
```

E coloque no plural as tuas propriedades que são lista. use `ICollection<Curso> Cursos`

Boa sorte

Comment: Não deu certo!!

Comment: O que não deu certo ? continua dando erro de validação ? O entity conseguiu criar o mapeamento corretamente ?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui chegar a uma solução.

Não sei ao certo o por que isso dá certo, ou se faz sentido dar certo.

### Solução

Se antes de atualizar eu der um `Clear()` na lista, ele não gera mais o erro.

Ou seja:

```
var idsCoordenacao = entidade.Coordenacao.Select(c => c.Id).ToList();
var coordenacao = contexto.CorpoDocente.Where(cd => idsCoordenacao.Contains(cd.Id)).ToList();
if (entidade.Id > 0)
{
    var cursoAlterar = contexto.Curso.First(x => x.Id == entidade.Id);
    cursoAlterar.Titulo = entidade.Titulo;
    cursoAlterar.Coordenacao.Clear(); //ADICIONAR ESSA LINHA.
    cursoAlterar.Coordenacao = coordenacao;
    contexto.Entry(cursoAlterar).State = EntityState.Modified;
    contexto.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Na verdade isso só faz você excluir os registros antigos e adicionar novos. Funciona, mas sua aplicação fará a exclusão seguida da inserção todas as vezes.